# SSRS - Lookup field exported shown as #Error

Tags: excel, csv, reporting-services

I was wondering if anybody else came across the same problem. It's been bugging me for weeks now.

I have a big table in my report pulling data from DataSet A, one column contains data from DataSet B and is pulled using the followin:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Date.Value, Fields!Date.Value, Fields!Sales.Value, "Sales")
```

Running report shows no errors, all numbers are displayed. However when I export the report to any format (tried CSV, EXCEL, PDF) the value from lookup column comes as #Error (CSV, PDF) or #VALUE! (EXCEL).

Looking for any help on the internet proved to be unsuccessful. Is there anybody who stumpled upon the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the fact that I was returning more than one row from the other dataset (not always but in some cases yes). Normally I would create calculate field (different currencies and sales value) and sum them in the report. SSRS didn't have problem showing the first value by default but export functionality failed, since I did't SUM() rows that were find. I change the Dataset then to calculate the values after currency conversion and them wrapped it in another select statement to make sure I only have one for my Date.Value

Answer (score 0):

If you can lookup the data field from another dataset properly, it should not be the issue on lookup() function. I've also tested in my local environment, the data can be rendered after exporting. In this scenario, I suggest pay attention to the data type and data length. Can you show the sample data in your BIDS/SSDT?